# Get windows username from anonymous authentication

Tags: reactjs, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

I have two apps hosted on the same server in IIS.
One is a .NET core API which has anonymous authentication enabled and windows authentication disabled and the other is a react site that has anonymous authentication disabled and windows authentication enabled.

When the user navigates to the web app, they get prompted for a login as expected. How can I pass that login username when making a call to the API? When inspecting "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" it is empty which makes sense. Is there a different property I can look at?

Is there a way I can store the username in a cookie or something?

Thanks

Comment: Anonymous authentication means it access everything under anonymous user like IUSR. So you can't fetch windows user from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.  If you want to pass username to core API. Please encrypt  the username and put it in either header or request body.

Comment: How would I get the user name from within the react app? I don't have access to os or env. I would love to store it in the header or request body.

Comment: I think you need to change code in react app and run something like imersonation in asp.net core application.